# Answers to deleted questions are still being used in review audits

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-audits, deleted-questions

I was reviewing the low-quality queue, and [this answer audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5262299) came up:

[image]

I edited the pre-review state of the answer into the screenshot above, because I had already passed the *obvious review audit* at this point. (In case you haven't figured it out, **the question itself had already been deleted**, thus the pale greyish-pink background).

According to [Answer to a deleted question being used as review audit in first posts queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194128/163250), **answers to deleted questions were supposed to be excluded** from review audits since September 30<sup>th</sup>, 2013, approximately 10 months ago.

It looks like this isn't quite fixed yet.

Comment: Makes me wonder if review audits, once selected, get saved in a list somewhere for continued re-use. That answer was first used as an audit on June 16, before the question was deleted. So maybe it doesn't keep re-checking if the question state has changed?

Comment: I'm checking this out now. Looks like we just missed the check for deleted question in a few places, but verifying...

Comment: @Haney: http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5300516 This happened just now, got me suspended _\*grumbles\*_. ;-) It appears this still isn't quite fixed.

Comment: @Cerbrus you're not kidding. Let me see what I can figure out.

Comment: @Haney: I appreciate the effort :-) Any chance a fix could have an effect on the "side-effect" of that failed audit? ;-)

Comment: You never know... But probably not. :D

Comment: Yeah I messed up the fix by missing one check. I'll push a fix out for this as soon as our next prod build. Sorry about this!

Comment: Excellent! At least that's fixed, then :3

Comment: Checked in the change now. It'll be live next prod release (should be < 24 hours).

Comment: [possibly recurring](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326376/small-bug-in-test-review?lq=1) @Haney

Comment: @ryanyuyu yeah appears it might be. Put it on the agenda for our Monday meeting to discuss and possibly investigate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've changed the code so that answers for deleted questions will no longer appear in the Low Quality, First Post, or Late Answers review queues. This will be live in the next prod build.

Comment: Do you happen to have an idea when the "next prod build" is supposed to roll out?

Comment: @Cerbrus - it should be live as of late last week.

Comment: @Haney Seems like it might still be an issue: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267422/late-answer-and-deleted-question-review-audit?lq=1

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267648/question-not-found-on-audit-possible-bug?cb=1

Comment: @Haney Seems it is still not fixed or it is just test for reviwers (which are held sometimes): http://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/6088162

Comment: @YulianKhlevnoy I have confirmed that review task `6088162` was an audit/test to be passed, so that would explain why this appeared. Shouldn't for live / non-audit reviews.

Comment: @Haney, understood. (I clicked "Skip" and nothing happened, just a new review task.) Now, it all became clear.

Comment: Appears to still be happening:  http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11658226 http://i.stack.imgur.com/91TT9.png

Comment: And here: http://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/11853971 http://i.imgur.com/GyFP9Pp.png?1

Comment: According to Oded, answer audit reviews should not be used if the question is deleted http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/198922/213575 This is not the case http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324008/removed-dead-questions-in-late-answers-audit?lq=1