# Late Answer [and Deleted Question] Review Audit

Tags: bug, review-audits, deleted-questions

Just wanted to mention that it seems strange to have review audits for the Late Answer Queue in which the original question has been deleted.

Here's an example of [one I just had](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/5439161). In this case I probably could have down-voted the answer, but as it was possible that it did address the deleted invisible question satisfactorily, I chose not to take any action.

Edit: Just saw that [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265278/3124288) says the issue should have been fixed - it appears it is not.

Comment: sorry I may have missed something here but how is your question not a duplicate of [this one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/263155/answers-to-deleted-questions-are-still-being-used-in-review-audits/). Is it because of the `status-completed` tag but the audit still happens on the deleted questions? I have just had one this morning as well but I thought it actually was a good audit.

Comment: I actually did notice that question (I added a link to one of its answers in my question a few minutes after creating the question). You're right though, in hindsight it probably is more or less a duplicate, the main thing of note is that it says this issue was fixed a few weeks ago but it doesn't seem to have been.