# "question not found" on audit (possible bug)

Tags: bug, review-queues

When *question not found* is presented during review, it usually means its an audit question. I think this may be a bug.

Perhaps its would be a better idea to *not* leak information.

[image]

Comment: I think its a test to weed out the **really** oblivious (*dumb*) people reviewing.

Comment: Do you have an example - can you link to a specific review?

Comment: @slugster: [Here’s the review in the screenshot.](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5455727)

Comment: That's weird, this was meant to be fixed: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/263155/answers-to-deleted-questions-are-still-being-used-in-review-audits

Comment: Now it has both _answer not found_ **and** _question not found_.

Comment: For 10k users, the deleted question and answer are both shown.

Comment: The bug still persists as of April 2016. Wow.