# Audit answer with missing question?

Tags: bug, review-audits

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/8331614

Kind of odd, As soon as I read the answer I saw "question not found" where the question should have been. This immediately signaled to me that it was in fact an audit (as I doubt I would be reviewing a real answer with no question). I submitted my review and passed.

Is this a bug, or will there actually be a situation where I am going to be reviewing an answer with no question?

I'm guessing this has to do with the question being deleted and not having > 10k rep, but shouldn't the question still be viewable in the review queue even so?

What is doubly odd is that I can see the question after submitting the review, (still only in the review queue).

Comment: It's entirely possible for both the answer and question to be deleted separately on their own merits, maybe you just happened to get one of those as an audit? I assume a 10k user would have a better idea.

Comment: @DennisMeng that's what I was thinking, but seeing no question for an answer is a pretty dead giveaway that its an audit (I would think)

Comment: An audit is just a copy of a real Q+A with poster names obfuscated.  So isn't affected by this particular one getting deleted 16 hours ago.  You can always tell you're being audited, just compare to the original.  All they want to test is whether you are paying attention and filter out the robo-reviewers.  You were paying attention so easily passed.

Comment: Hmm, seems to be a regression: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/263155/answers-to-deleted-questions-are-still-being-used-in-review-audits