# Missing question bug within late answers audit

Tags: bug, review-audits

According to this [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/263155/answers-to-deleted-questions-are-still-being-used-in-review-audits) the bug whereby deleted questions were appearing in review audits should have been fixed over a year ago.

I was reviewing the late answers queue today and one such case appeared.  The question was showing as "question does not exist".  I passed the audit by flagging the answer for moderation attention (specifying that the question does not exist).  I suspect, by being a test, this flag never made it to a moderator.

I managed to get a screenshot after passing the audit:

[image: audit problem]