# Removed dead questions in late answers Audit

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-audits

According to [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265278/5832518), the bug was fixed. Looks like [it is not](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/12508699).

[image: Review Audit without question]

Comment: Maybe next production build is not out yet? It's only been two years you know...

Comment: Wait was this a bug? I thought it was just an obvious audit... :P

Comment: Doesn't "late" mean dead?

Comment: Shhhh... Don't tell them about it! It'll make it harder to see which reviews are audits when robo-reviewing

Comment: @AndrewGrimm [Late answers](http://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/stats) is a review queue. It contains answers from new users which were posted much later than the question.

Comment: @NathanOliver According to a [comment on the answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/263155/answers-to-deleted-questions-are-still-being-used-in-review-audits#comment349526_265278) linked in the question, this one is _actually_ a bug and not just audits being insanely easy. So that duplicate would be incorrect here.

Comment: @Kendra Ah.  I'll remove my vote and comment.

Comment: I am pretty sure, the production build will be out in about 6-8 weeks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed rolling out in next build (build rev `2016.7.1.4698` on MSE/MSO, `2016.7.1.3721` on sites)