# Small bug in test review

Tags: discussion, bug, review-queues, review-audits

I just made some reviews and faces [test in it](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/12724535) (audit). If you go by the link you see already a result of audit, but when I saw it first time question field was blank (something about 'cannot find the question') because question was already deleted!

It's not only obvious that it's audit but I suppose it's not correct to review the answer without question.

Unfortunately, I didn't do screenshot of this example so can't show it to you.

Is it ok or is it a bug?

Comment: Just to make sure, while you looked at the audit in review, the question for the answer was not found?  This might actually be a bug.

Comment: [Audit are supposed to be obvious](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288046/this-review-is-obviously-an-audit-is-this-a-bug/288047#288047).  Just maybe not that obvious.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Yep it was only inscription something like 'question cannot be found'.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Ye I read it too before post the question. But still is it correct to suppose audit without question? I think no

Comment: Well it certainly raises a lot of red flags that it is an audit.  Again, I don't know if they were intended to be _this_ obvious.

Comment: This is just a small thing, but since the problem is recurring, is duplicate closure the best action here @NathanOliver?  It does appear to be the same problem.

Comment: @ryanyuyu If it is the same problem then shouldn't it be closed as a dupe.  Adding more questions will not force SO to move faster on something that really doesn't affect the usability of the site.

Comment: @NathanOliver I guess that's true.